# Having trouble with Python's telnetlib module

Tags: python, telnet

I have a basic chat server which I can easily connect to with telnet. I simply enter the host and port and, without any further authentication, can begin entering commands that the server can interpret. In an effort to simulate user traffic, I would like to create a script that will open telnet, connect to the server, and immediately begin sending commands to the server. I initially attempted to do this with batch scripts, but after encountering too many road blocks I have decided to use Python's telnetlib module. This is what the script looks like now

```
import telnetlib
myTel = telnetlib.Telnet('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', XXXX)
myTel.write('login')
myTel.write('move room')
myTel.write('say message')
myTel.write('exit')
myTel.write('logout')
```

Its really that simple and the script runs with no errors. However, if I've already manually logged into the server on another telnet session, I fail to see the script entering the main room or sending a chat message which leads me to believe that something is going wrong. If I manually start two telnet sessions I can easily send and receive messages between the sessions, so I would think that a manual telnet session should be receiving the messages from the session started by the script.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps adding a newline would help?

```
myTel.write('login\n')
```

I'd also recommend using some network sniffing tool (i.e. Wireshark) to verify that you're really sending what you intended.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you write to the server, but in order to receive data, you'll eventually have to one of the [read methods](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.read_until) of the library. To see an example implementation of a client with a 'reading thread', see this blog post: http://hahong.org/blog/posts/261.

fn. Also try:

```
myTel.write('login\n')
```

.. with newlines.

Comment: The very next sentence reads: "Alternatively, the host name and optional port and timeout can be passed to the constructor, in which case the connection to the server will be established before the constructor returns."

Comment: I added some read_until commands to my script along with adding a \n to the string in each write command and still nothing. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I would use read_until to check that the server is ready to receive the command here is a sample using telnet to talk to a cisco switch:

```
from telnetlib import Telnet
PASSWD = "mypass"

t = Telnet(switch)
t.read_until("Password: ", 2)
t.write(PASSWD + "\r\n")
```

Here I wait for a password prompt before sending the password.